# Sitecore CM and CD in the same server

Tags: deployment, scaling

We have a requirement to have the CM and CD in the same server.

But while we are trying to access the CD URL as www.xyz.com/sitecore we are landing to the sitecore admin page.

Is there a way to deny access to the admin page with CD url.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that with "same server" you are talking about the same instance (otherwise you just need to apply the [hardering setup](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_hardening)).

In this case, a possible solution could be to use the IIS rewrite module to set redirects on the folders you want to deny on the CD url. Put a redirect on `/sitecore/admin`, `/sitecore/debug`, `/sitecore/login`, `/sitecore/shell/WebService` and all their children to any path you want (e.g. your homepage)

Edit: as Jose mentioned: this approach does require 2 domain names to make a distinction between CM and CD. Best practice would be to make the CM not publicly available.

ps: don't do this for the entire /sitecore folder.. that would break your CD.

Comment: Needs to assign 2 domains to the site so can be accessed from CM

Comment: Sitecore will still run all the CM pipelines on the CD URL. So if you put ?sc_mode=edit on the URL for example then you'll have issues. To fix that, you'll need to have another site on the config with enableWebEdit=false etc

Answer (score 1):

Go to IIS. Select **Admin** folder under the **Sitecore** folder. In **Feature View**, Double click on **Authentication**.

[image]

Select **Anonymous Authentication** and click **Disable**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also deny access to the sitecore folder in the web.config, but keep in mind that some directories should be accessable:

```
<!-- Deny users access to internal paths -->
<location path="sitecore" xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="sitecore modules" xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="sitecore/service" xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
            <!--heartbeat, keepalive, ect. must be accessible-->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="sitecore/shell/Webservice/Service.asmx" xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
            <!--allow webservice-->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="sitecore modules/Web/Web Forms for Marketers/mvc" xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
            <!--allow WFFM Assets -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

As you can see we use XML-Transformation to do that on CD-Server config only.

Best regards
Dirk